# Chrome SVG rendering bug in MacOSX Sierra?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, svg

I have a Google Chrome problem on macOS Sierra: [Image: SVG rendering bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5jI3.png)

As you can see in the image above, the SVG background images in the stackoverflow answering section are not rendered correctly. That also applies for the stackoverflow logo and for any other SVG background images.

I solved the problem temporary by deinstall and install Chrome again. The next day I had the same problem. Chrome is up to date on version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

I also have the issue that if I hover over an DOM element in the 'Elements' tab in dev-tools, the element is not highlighted on the page. This was also gone after reinstalling but also appeared the next day again.

Any ideas about these issues?

Comment: Interesting.  If you load the SVG directly in its own browser window, does it render correctly? https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/wmd-buttons.svg

Comment: No, same rendering bug. If I reboot it's gone for a while, really weird!

Comment: Same issue on Yosemite 10.10.5 with current Chrome (Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) Seems to be a strange chrome bug.